# React - setState in componentWillMount() results in a UI lag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have to fetch some data in `componentWillMount()`, this takes some time (2 second), After this, I use `setState` to Update some values in the state, since this `setState` re-renders the UI, there is a delay between the component initial render and the render from setState, Is there any way to fix this UI lag?

**Update**: 
if I want to use a loading indicator, where should I put it? I use a promise to fetch my data like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  api.getData().then((response) => { ... }
```

Comment: if it takes 2 seconds to fetch data, there will always be 2 seconds delay between initial render and `setState` triggering a render.  Are you asking how to prevent all rendering until after data is fetched?

Comment: No, is it possible to prevent all rendering?

Comment: I mean isn't that the whole point of a SPA app?  Instead of HTML coming down from the server with data, you load the skeleton first and load the data after your async returns.  I'm not sure how you would avoid this situation, its either load the skeleton (have a loading indicator) then load the data or keep the page blank and load the data + skeleton after which i'm not sure why that would be better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should never use async operations in `componentWillMount` or the `constructor`.
Instead do it in `componentDidMount`.
You can read about it in the [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)

> setting state synchronously in this method will not trigger a
>   re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in
>   this method.

**Edit**
As a followup to your updated question

> if I want to use a loading indicator, where should I put it? I use a
>   promise to fetch my data

I've made a small example of fetching data and rendering a loader while data is being fetched.

In this example i'm using a free API tester called [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com), I'm using this [URL](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) to fetch some random data of users.
You can see that i initialize the state **in the `contructor`** with an empty array of `users`, I'm fetching the users **in the `componentDidMount` life cycle method** and updating the `users` array of the state inside the callback of the promise that has returned.  Note that i did that inside a `setTimeOut` method in order to get a delay of 2 seconds.

Now, React won't really going to wait for our ajax request to get back with the results, it will invoke the `render` method no matter what, hence doing the ajax request in a life cycle method that runs before the `render` method (like `componentWillMount` or the `constructor`) is not a best practice as mentioned above, so that's why we do it inside the `componentDidMount` method.

You probably asking, *Ok then! But HOW and WHAT should i render **before** the data is received and then render the data **after** it is received?* I'm glad you asked :)

We can use the life cycle of react to work for us and take advantage of the powerful render options and state updates.
In this example I conditionally rendered a `<Loader />` or the data `<UserList/>` with the help of the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
return ({this.state.users.length > 0 ? <UserList /> : <Loader/>);
```

This way, when ever the `users` array of state is empty it will render the `Loader` component, after the state will updated (which will happen after the ajax request is finished) the `render` method will be invoked again but this time the condition will return `true` thus the `UserList` will render and **not** the `Loader`.

**Here is the full running example:**

```js
const apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

const User = ({ name, username, email }) => (
  <div style={{ border: "1px solid #ccc", padding: "15px" }}>
    <div>Name: {name}</div>
    <div>User Name: {username}</div>
    <div>E-Mail: {email}</div>
  </div>
);

const UserList = ({ users }) =>(
  <div>
    {users.map(user => <User key={user.id} {...user} />)}
  </div>
);

const Loader = () => (
<div id="escapingBallG">
 <div id="escapingBall_1" className="escapingBallG"></div>
</div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // mimic 2 seconds delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      axios.get(apiUrl)
        .then(users => {
          this.setState({
            users: [...users.data]
          });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }, 2000);
  }
  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          users.length > 0 ? <UserList users={users} /> : <Loader />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
#escapingBallG{
 position:relative;
 width:125px;
 height:43px;
 margin:auto;
}

.escapingBallG{
 background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:43px;
 height:43px;
 border-radius:21px;
  -o-border-radius:21px;
  -ms-border-radius:21px;
  -webkit-border-radius:21px;
  -moz-border-radius:21px;
 animation-name:bounce_escapingBallG;
  -o-animation-name:bounce_escapingBallG;
  -ms-animation-name:bounce_escapingBallG;
  -webkit-animation-name:bounce_escapingBallG;
  -moz-animation-name:bounce_escapingBallG;
 animation-duration:1.5s;
  -o-animation-duration:1.5s;
  -ms-animation-duration:1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1.5s;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-timing-function:linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function:linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function:linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
 animation-delay:0s;
  -o-animation-delay:0s;
  -ms-animation-delay:0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0s;
  -moz-animation-delay:0s;
 transform:scale(0.5, 1);
  -o-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
  -ms-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
  -moz-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
}



@keyframes bounce_escapingBallG{
 0%{
  left:0px;
  transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }

 25%{
  left:41px;
  transform:scale(1, 0.5);
 }

 50%{
  left:103px;
  transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }

 75%{
  left:41px;
  transform:scale(1, 0.5);
 }

 100%{
  left:0px;
  transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce_escapingBallG{
 0%{
  left:0px;
  -o-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }

 25%{
  left:41px;
  -o-transform:scale(1, 0.5);
 }

 50%{
  left:103px;
  -o-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }

 75%{
  left:41px;
  -o-transform:scale(1, 0.5);
 }

 100%{
  left:0px;
  -o-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_escapingBallG{
 0%{
  left:0px;
  -ms-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }

 25%{
  left:41px;
  -ms-transform:scale(1, 0.5);
 }

 50%{
  left:103px;
  -ms-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }

 75%{
  left:41px;
  -ms-transform:scale(1, 0.5);
 }

 100%{
  left:0px;
  -ms-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_escapingBallG{
 0%{
  left:0px;
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }

 25%{
  left:41px;
  -webkit-transform:scale(1, 0.5);
 }

 50%{
  left:103px;
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }

 75%{
  left:41px;
  -webkit-transform:scale(1, 0.5);
 }

 100%{
  left:0px;
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_escapingBallG{
 0%{
  left:0px;
  -moz-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }

 25%{
  left:41px;
  -moz-transform:scale(1, 0.5);
 }

 50%{
  left:103px;
  -moz-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }

 75%{
  left:41px;
  -moz-transform:scale(1, 0.5);
 }

 100%{
  left:0px;
  -moz-transform:scale(0.5, 1);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: for me, componentDidMount cause the same issue.

Comment: how so? `componentDidMount` will be invoked after the `render` hence you already have your component visualized.

Comment: since setState cause a re-render, there is still a lag.

Comment: its hard to know whats going on as you didn't include any code example in your question

Comment: @AdelMemariani Of course there's a lag if you're doing work--what do you expect? Your component has to be able to handle rendering before data is available.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will help, you can add loading state till you get all your data and setState. then make the loading sate to false and then render data

```
class Project extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        data : data
    };
}


componentDidMount() {
    this
        .props
        .GetData(this.state)
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState.isLoading = false;
        }, (err) => this.setState({errors: err.response}));
}


render() {
     const { isLoading, data} = this.props;

    if(isLoading){
        return (
               <p>loading!!!</p>
        );

    return (
        <p>data</p>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: @sag1v are you talking about loading states? Could you point me to the docs to avoid loading states, I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @pk1m I was talking about side effects in `componentWillMount`. You can see a link to it in my answer.

Comment: @Sag1v as the question was about the delay in render, suggestion was to load a **default state** before the **data** is fetched and re rendered, hence suggested **componentWillMount**

Comment: @harshapatil In your answer you're not loading default state in `componentWillMount` yet you do ajax request (side effect) in it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing with your fetched data (for instance rendering a long list of items), you might consider fetching the data in smaller chunks or pages. This will allow your component to render a small set of the data, and you can load in the rest behind the scenes, or as the user interacts with the view.